# Submonoid of free monoid with certain properties

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids

Let $N$ be a submonoid of a free monoid $M$ such that

$m_1nm_2\in N \Rightarrow m_1,m_2\in N$ for any $m_1,m_2\in M$ and $n\in N\setminus\{1\}$.       $\quad\quad\quad\quad$     (C)

Do such submonoids $N$ have a name?

Comment: Identify $M$ with the set of all finite words over some alphabet $X$. I think that if one drops the condition $n\neq 1$, then the submonoids $N$ described in my question are precisely the submonoids of $M$ generated by some subset $Y\subseteq X$ (because $N$ has to contain any letter of a word in $N$).

Comment: A submonoid $N$ is called unitary if $mn,n\in N$ implies $m\in N$ and $nm,n\in N$ implies $m\in N$. Clearly your condition implies unitary. I first thought it is the same but maybe it is stronger.

Comment: I think it is stronger: Let $M$ be the free monoid on the set $\{a,b\}$, and $N$ the submonoid generated by $\{ab,ba\}$. Then $N$ is unitary but does not satisfy my condition. For example $a(ba)b, ba\in N$ but $a,b\not\in N$.

Comment: No, that is not true. If you write a $w\in N$ as $pn$, then $n$ does not have to lie in $N$. For example, let again $M$ be the free monoid on $\{a,b\}$ and $N$ the submonoid generated by the word $ab$. Then $N$ satisfies my condition but is not generated by some of the free generators of $M$.

Comment: Did you look in Berstel and Reutenauer?

Comment: https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/1655-13.pdf looks at the weaker condition that $n,xny\in N$ implies $xy\in N$.

Comment: I looked in the book "Codes and Automata" by Berstel, Perrin and Reutenauer (did you mean that?). There they define a pure monoid as a submonoid $M$ of a free monoid $A^*$ such that for any $x\in A^*$ and $n\geq 1$, $x^n\in M\Rightarrow x\in M$. They define a very pure monoid as a submonoid $M$ of a free monoid $A^*$ such that for any $u,v\in A^*$, $uv,vu\in M\Rightarrow u,v\in M$. I think submonoids $M$ of $A^*$ satisfying my condition are very pure, since if $uv,vu\in M$, then $u(vu)v, vu\in M$ and hence $u,v\in M$.

Comment: Maybe it is a new condition then. That book is fairly complete

Answer (score 1):

Let $N$ be a submonoid of a free monoid $M$. Recall that $N$ has a unique minimal generating set, denoted by $\min(N)$, namely $(N\setminus 1) \setminus (N \setminus 1)^2$. According to Berstel-Perrin-Reutenauer, $N$ is right unitary (resp. left unitary, biunitary) if and only if $\min(N)$ is a prefix code (resp. suffix code, bifix code). If I haven't made a mistake, then $N$ satisfies the condition (C) in my question if and only if $\min(N)$ is a "cover code", meaning that one cannot cover a word in $\min(N)$ by  words in $\min(N)$ in a nontrivial way (see the Definition below).

**Definition** Let $X^*$ be the set of finite words over some alphabet $X$ and $W\subseteq X^*$ a subset. Define a *cover* of a word $w\in W$ as a tuple $(w_1,\dots, w_k,\alpha,\beta)$ where $w_1,\dots,w_k\in W$ and $\alpha,\beta\in X^*$, such that $$\alpha w \beta=w_1\dots w_k, ~~~|w_1|>|\alpha|,~~~|w_k|>|\beta|.$$ Call a cover $(w_1,\dots,w_k,\alpha,\beta)$ of $w$ *trivial* if $k=1$, $w_1=w$ and $\alpha=\beta=1$. The set $W$ is a *cover code* if every $w\in W$ can only be covered trivially.

**Lemma** Let $N$ be a submonoid of a free monoid $M=X^*$. Then $N$ satisfies condition (C) if and only if $\min(N)$ is a cover code.

**Proof** ($\Rightarrow$) Suppose $N$ satisfies (C). Let $w\in \min(N)$ and $(w_1,\dots,w_k,\alpha,\beta)$ a cover of $w$. Since $N$ satisfies (C), we have $\alpha,\beta\in N$. Hence $\alpha=w_{\alpha,1}\dots w_{\alpha,r}$ and $\beta=w_{\beta,1}\dots w_{\beta,s}$ for some $w_{\alpha,i},w_{\beta,j}\in \min(N)$. Since $N$ satisfies (C), no word in $\min(N)$ has a proper subword lying in $N$. It follows, that
$$w_1=w_{\alpha,1},~\dots ~, w_r=w_{\alpha,r},~ w_{r+1}=w,~w_{r+2}=w_{\beta,1},~\dots~, w_k=w_{\beta,s}.$$
Since $|w_1|>|\alpha|$ and $|w_k|>|\beta|$, it follows that $\alpha=\beta=1$ and moreover that $k=1$ and $w_1=w$, i.e. $(w_1,\dots,w_k,\alpha,\beta)$ is trivial.

($\Leftarrow$) Suppose that $\min(N)$ is a cover code. Let $m_1,m_2\in M, n\in N\setminus\{1\}$ such that $m_1nm_2\in N$. Write $$n=w_{n,1}\dots w_{n,k}~\text{ and }~m_1nm_2= w_1\dots w_l$$ where $w_{n,1},\dots, w_{n,k},w_1,\dots, w_l\in \min(N)$. Let the integer $p$ be maximal with the property $|w_1\dots w_p|\leq|m_1|$. Then there is a $q\geq p+1$ and $\alpha,\beta\in M$ such that $(w_{p+1},\dots,w_{q},\alpha,\beta)$ is a cover of $w_{n,1}$. Since $\min(N)$ is a cover code, it follows that $q=p+1$ and $w_{p+1}=w_{n,1}$. Hence there is a $q'\geq p+2$ and $\alpha',\beta'\in M$ such that $(w_{p+2},\dots,w_{q'},\alpha',\beta')$ is a cover of $w_{n,2}$. It follows that $q'=p+2$ and $w_{p+2}=w_{n,2}$. Proceeding like this we get
$$n=w_{n,1}\dots w_{n,k}=w_{p+1}\dots w_{p+k}.$$
It follows that $m_1=w_1\dots w_p,~m_2=w_{p+k+1}\dots w_{l}\in N$. Thus $N$ satisfies condition (C).$~~\quad\Box$

**Examples** Let $X=\{a,b\}$ and $M=X^*$. Let
$$N_1=\langle aa\rangle,~~ N_2=\langle ab\rangle,~~ N_3=\langle ab, ba, bba\rangle.$$
Note that $\min(N_1)=N_1$, $\min(N_2)=N_2$ and $\min(N_3)=N_3$. $N_1$ does not satisfy condition (C) since $(aa,aa,a,a)$ is a nontrivial cover of $aa$. $N_2$ satisfies condition (C) since $ab$ has no nontrivial cover. $N_3$ does not satisfy condition (C) since $(ab,ba,a,1)$ is a nontrivial cover of $bba$.

Comment: A little addendum: The "cover codes" defined above seem to be known as "comma-free codes", see for example Berstel-Perrin-Reutenauer.